# How can I make sure a webcam for NB505 is working when it doesn't show image?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, drivers, webcam

I have a NB505 mini laptop which has a built in webcam. However it doesn't display any image. I tried to reintall the drivers from Toshiba. I'm currently using Windows 7 Starter (which is the version that came with this laptop) and it indicates that the driver being used is USB 2.0 Camera. Seen in the picture from below.

[image: Screenshot of the device settings]

However the camera doesn't show any image is still shows no image but instead a dark screen. Does it exist some sort of software or anything that I can do in the registry to test if the webcam is not damaged?. Perhaps does it exist some utility used to troubleshoot or anything?.

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

Toshiba support for this kind of laptop is not available now. Thus I don't know what else I can do. I have installed ESET Internet security which does integration with devices such as webcam and microphone. But I made sure that the option for blocking webcam or microphone is disabled thus it should not be a problem, but I'm still getting a dark screen.

Can someone help me?. Please don't say just buy a webcam or use another computer. As at this moment these aren't options and my intention is to actually use use the webcam which came with my laptop.

Comment: You can find your user manual, if you don't have one here https://support.dynabook.com/support/modelHome?freeText=2861099 Approx. 3 MB. Accoring to your book "The Web Camera indicator light glows when the Web Camera is active. For more information on the software, click Start, All Programs, TOSHIBA, Utilities, and then Web Camera 
Application Help."

Comment: @vssher The Web Camera doesn't light now. But it did just a moment ago. I'm not sure what's going on. When it led turned on the driver shown Toshiba Web Cam in Device manager. But now it only shows USB 2.0 Web camera as it is shown in my screenshot. I am starting to believe that it might be some conflict with ESET Antivirus? because when I connected to the Wifi network the webcam didn't shown any image. It is strange.